# Do SQLiteStatements need to be closed?

Tags: android, sqlite

In Android's sqlite classes, there is a class called `SQLiteStatement` which you can obtain by compiling a statement with [SqliteDatabase.compileStatement()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement(java.lang.String))

It subclasses [SQLiteClosable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteClosable.html) which like a Cursor object has a `close` method.

I know with Cursor's we need to becareful to close them, but what about statements? Do they need to be closed ever?

Comment: By looking into codes, the close is the counter of acquireReference http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.java#SQLiteStatement most calls are delivered for SQLiteProgram actually (it extends it and SQLiteCloseable indirectly) you can check what it do.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLiteStatement` is the Java representation of the [sqlite3_stmt object](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html). As long as it is alive, it will occupy not only memory in the Java heap, but also in SQLite's internal data structures. Furthermore, active statements will prevent the connection (`SQLiteDatabase`) from closing.
(And we can assume that the author of this package didn't derive from `SQLiteClosable` just for fun …)